# How to send a password securley with REST

Tags: c#, php, rest, security, encryption

I currently work on a project in C# with a login system. I use a REST API to handle the database stuff. Currently I only use SHA-1 encryption for my system but I want to switch to the PHP password_hash() thing. The one problem of mine is that I don't know how to request the password from the client because now I just send the SHA-1 hash which is the same as in the database. Does anyone know a secure solution?

Sincerely,
Paul

Comment: What is wrong with htttps?

Comment: How not to store Passwords: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q | The salting approach still seems to be current, btw.

Comment: 1 way hash with salt using https.  SHA-1 is ok but c# has better encryption algorithms available to it in comparison with php.  But auth security is only as good as your server security i would not overly concern about hashing once you 1 way hash with a salt.  That makes it far more difficult to crack without knowing the salt.  You also could store devices and use devices as an additional key to the authentication process.

Comment: If you simply hash the password on the client side, then the hash _is_ the password. Use TLS and just send the password in plaintext. If the service can't be permitted to ever actually see the plaintext password, then you need a completely different authentication workflow.

Comment: So is it enough if I send the plain password through https to the request and then just store it securly in the database with the salting system of php?